# iPhone Leak on UITextfield text

Tags: iphone, ios

Instruments tools says this is a leak but I can't figure out why, any ideas?

[image]

Comment: I suspect the ans=@"" is causing the leak, since ans was already allocated.  If you release ans before assigning, does that fix the leak?

Comment: @Alan Moore thats autorelase why would I release it?

Comment: The answer below pretty well says it.  Since you are assigning to a constant string it is messing up the autorelease -- that's my guess anyway.  Normally you would not need to release.  I think @Francisco has it right.

Comment: Aside from the answers people have already given you, what is the purpose of this code in the first place?  It seems to me you can eliminate all of that string handling.  You initialise a string variable with the value of the text property of a text field.  You then look to see if it is empty, and if it is, you set it to empty - when it would already be empty.  You then add the new string to an array.  Why didn't you just add `[[textField.text mutableCopy] autorelease]` to the array?

Comment: @Jim I just tried to set it to empty string rather than null if textfield is never edited. can you tell me why its not necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are releasing `self.variables` property in your dealloc (or somewhere).  Also, ensure that your `Variable` class is releasing `variableValues` property in the `Variable` class's dealloc.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a proper way to assign `@""` to a `NSMutableString`. You should use `setString:` instead.

Comment: tnx I tried but still leaks same, its about textfield.text I guess