# iPhone Leak while reading string value

Tags: iphone, ios

Instruments tools says this is a leak, any ideas?

**I release the variable object by end of the for loop**

[image]

[image]

and by the begininng of the method above this is how I set the variables obkect, thats autorelease;

```
NSMutableArray *variables = nil; 
if (self.responseXMLData) {
    variables = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
            //here is the all the code in the if statement which posted the screen shots
```

Comment: Can you include more code?  As danWombourne pointed at, the code will leak if you don't balance your retainCount with releases.  Is `variable` being added to collections that either aren't being released?  This is a common reason for leaks it seems.  Also, make sure that `domainItems` is being released either in this function or dealloc.

Comment: Are you releasing `variables` (the collection, not `variable`) somewhere?  I'm assuming you alloc init the variables collection in your init.  Double check that you release it in dealloc.

Comment: @Sam tnx it is autorelease, pls see the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are releasing `self.variables` property in your dealloc (or somewhere).  Also, ensure that your `Variable` class is releasing `variableValues` property in the `Variable` class's dealloc.

Same answer from related question: [iPhone Leak on UITextfield text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472242/iphone-leak-on-uitextfield-text/7472870#7472870)

Answer (score 2):

To all the new readers, after the edit to the question; this isn't the answer !

---

Yes.

You don't release `variables` anywhere.

You call `alloc] init]` so it's your responsibility to `release` it :)

Comment: No No if you meant "variable" I release it by end of the for loop

Comment: Where? From the looks of it, the loop ends after domainItems. You should be placing a release after [domainItems release].

Comment: Are you releasing domainItems in your Variable's dealloc method?